# What is that "New contributor" icon supposed to be?

Tags: discussion, support, new-contributor-indicator

I read through most of [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator) but found no answers.

What is this?

[image]

Here are my best theories at the moment:

- A friendly hand waving and saying hi?
- A halting hand, warning old timers to be nice?
- A round of applause to encourage newcomers?

Is this icon open to interpretation or is there some final word on what exactly that hand is doing?

**Update:** I am now aware of the icon title "iconWave" - however, for me this really doesn't give me the full insight I am looking for.  Icons frequently have names that don't quite reflect their intended use.  Also, if it *is* in fact a wave, who is it waving at?  Is it waving at the OP in a friendly way?  Or is it waving at answerers to call attention to things?

Comment: `<svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconWave"` ← **`iconWave`**

Comment: It's a threatening hand, reaching out of the screen to grab you and drag you down to the depths of `/dev/null` from which it originated.

Comment: Not waving, but drowning.

Comment: Snipes and attacks at the site's new policies really doesn't help to solve any issues. If questioner, answerers and commenters have something constructive to to add to actually help define or solve perceived problems, by all means do so, without the layers of sarcasm and mockery that doesn't help and just reeks of "wow the site sucks"

Comment: While I somewhat agree with your point, the new user indicator having never been discussed, as far as I was aware, before being forced on the site, along with the not so subtle implication that new users should be treated with favoritism, makes for very good motivation to be snarky...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I have no issue with people not wanting it or liking it. But we've been through this upheaval of complaints since the welcoming blog. Instead of lamenting can we offer up something to the SE heads that can be actionable? It's getting old.

Comment: Real wow moment here.  This was a genuine and sincere question.  Part of my job involves icon design and I saw the new icon for the first time last night and was scratching my head wondering what the image was meant to convey. Can either of the close-voters please make a suggestion for how I can edit my question?

Comment: @billynoah if it's a genuine question, that's fine. Take out the "A round of applause to encourage newcomers?". We all know it's not that. A sensible discussion about it is welcome here. I don't want it derailed into a nonsense thread (as the top voted answer is heading). It should be discussed so we can actually answer it.

Comment: Honestly though, is it _that hard_ to tell? I'm not a professional icon designer or something but it feels obvious that it is, in fact, a waving hand. Maybe that's just me though..

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Maybe I'm an odd-ball but honestly, the round of applause was *my first thought* when I saw it.  I thought it might be trying to encourage the new poster with some positive re-enforcement.  I don't see why that's bad.  Thank you for responding and despite the fact that you answered my call for criticism, I don't want to edit that part out because it reflects what I really thought and would feel a bit weird to remove it.

Comment: Yes I am willing to edit the question.  But ***there is no snark***.  Please stop accusing me of that.

Comment: [Duplicate at meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1).

Comment: @Stijn The answers just happen to be like that. Not the question.

Comment: @user202729 I have a hard time taking this question serious with the *"A round of applause to encourage newcomers"* line in it, looks like mocking to me. Anyway, since OP says they did not mean it that way, I'll try answering the question.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that this represents the new user waving at people who see their post, so that it's clear to these people that the OP is friendly, but (as it seems to me) a little bit awkward, asking other people to _be nice_ to them.

Comment: The universal meanings of an open palm held out facing another person are:  "Stop", "Stay back", "I've had enough". I interpret it as a warning to stay away from posts written by beginners. Since new users are more likely to write crap questions and post homework dumps.

Comment: @Lundin, or is the universal meaning "I don't have a weapon in my hand"? There may be multiple meanings, to my mind, but a clearly _waving_ hand is more friendly than hostile.

Comment: The amount of hate being directed at my "round of applause" theory is a bit weird.  I really didn't mean anything bad by it.  The little pixels on either side of the hand look like movement to me.   A round of applause was my first thought and seems reasonable.

Comment: @ForceBru No, the universal meaning for that would be to hold out the hands and arms from  your sides.

Comment: @Lundin, this gesture looks like an attempt to prove someone wrong when they _accused_ you of having a weapon ("look, you thought I was gonna kill ya, but I don't even have a weapon"). Or, it can be seen as an "I don't know what to do" gesture. Again, there may be different gestures for one meaning and different meanings for one gesture. Still, a single waving hand (as opposed to two) is more of a greeting. If you start waving both hands furiously, then it's a clear sign you want someone to _not_ do something or go away.

Comment: The main problem is that the icon is vague. If we agree it's a waving hand, that's still very much culturally localized. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_(gesture)#Cultural_interpretations): a hand wave in Greece is an insulting gesture... I'd rather see the icon removed altogether. Iconography is hard, especially if you're not using signs or items.

Comment: @Stijn That's what "assume good faith" is supposed to mean. Assuming good faith, even and especially when it does not feel like it. Thinking that one's assuming good faith is totally easy when one agrees with content. It's assuming good faith in the face of content we do not agree with, or do not see how could be honest that is the actual lacking behaviour. EG one is not assuming good faith ever, if they do not do so even when they feel content is not honest.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank Jean-Luc Picard was deleted by [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson), presumably in response to a rude/abusive flag.

Comment: Is it a "goodbye"? I mean, I've never seen a "hello" wave.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - That's a really interesting angle I hadn't even considered.  Just want to say I don't necessarily think the vagueness is a problem though... icons don't *have* to have a single crystallized meaning to be effective.  As mentioned in my question, I wasn't sure if the creator meant to leave things a bit open ended, imply multiple meanings (as interpreted by Snow below) or if they in fact have a single, specific intention.

Comment: @billynoah after reading the comments and straining hard. I can actually see how you may have thought it was applause. I honestly couldn't see it and took it for sarcasm. I apologise for maligning you. Yes assuming good faith has been mentioned. A good thing for me work at.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank yeh, the post has shaped up well. At the start it didn't look so good. With a joke answer highly upvoted and I misconstrued the question.  I don't think SE is ignoring us. Theyr'e actually addressing many of out concerns and rolling them out. It seems they've changed tact and are doing it without asking exactly how. I think that's largely a good thing, as it's hard to get us all to agree. One thing we do agree on, is the problems. Besides if they roll our something we hate, they are quick to change it. Re, the not relevant comment debacle of 2018 :)

Comment: I mean... the teams ad is still a teams ad rather than a link, directly in the navbar... who else puts ads in the navbar?

Comment: @YvetteColomb - thanks for your understanding.  Maybe I have a weird way of seeing things but it truly was my first thought.  I can see how the Jean-Luc Picard answer might have rubbed someone the wrong way but to me it was funny.  The staff here have to deal with a lot of flack and covering one's face in despair might be any sane person's reaction.

Comment: @billynoah to be fair to you. I came here looking at the flag on the answer. The trend at the time in the comments and that answer made me think it was a bashing type of post. I really am sorry. I'm glad we sorted it out.

Comment: Another theory: from the *[EEVBlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_L._Jones_(video_blogger))* signature (one of surprise?) - see e.g. *[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4lIkonz7Rw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4lIkonz7Rw)* (from the original picture, shown at the very end - the last 20 seconds).

Comment: Can we have an icon, perhaps of a walker, for the old, decrepit users like myself? You know, the ones who ache when they get out of bed in the morning.

Comment: It looks like a drowning hand (seen from above) with water ripples around it. Might as well change it to a life-preserver.

Comment: @jpp I wave "hello" to people pretty regularly.

Comment: Would it be better as an animated GIF? Although I'm not sure how well that would work if people zoomed in to the page, but then I suppose they could read the text instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Stack Overflow threateningly raising its hand to remind us that disobedience will not be tolerated.

Comment: I honestly thought it was applause the first time I saw it.

Comment: A nice, pink and chubby hand would have been nice.

Comment: Could be a stylised Dove, to symbolise peace? Similar to https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hand-dove-holy-spirit-318500816

Comment: @Lundin even those meanings aren't universal.  Take for example [this image distributed by the US Marine Intelligence Agency](https://savageminds.org/wp-content/image-upload/1191840340_4054.gif). (Found in [this blog post](https://savageminds.org/2008/09/28/how-not-to-signal-stop/))

Comment: @NathanHinchey But someone failed to distribute the picture to the SO community, so I guess we stick with the _almost_ universal interpretation.

Comment: @Dukeling no, to me it reads as start of counting years until request to get rid of this indicator will be implemented, and we're apparently 5 years from that moment now (see [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/165773) - probably some just can't learn from past mistakes)

Comment: "Talk to the hand"

Comment: @YvetteColomb Offtopic, but: You might now start to **see** one problem with the "welcoming" discussion where you took a clear stance several times: When someone writes a question of which you are **deeply convinced** that is is a form of "trolling" (or maybe just "stupid"), and articulate that, and then have to apologize for what you considered to be absolutely justified, you end up at the point where you doubt whether you may express your thoughts freely, any time, **at all**. For me, that feels somewhat restricting and "arbitrarily oppressive". It's **really** difficult, that's for sure...

Comment: @Marco13 frankly it is very difficult. I feel hogtied (for want of a better expression) and it's not exclusive to the site (pun intended). We live in a world where everyone gets a participation award and children are not being prepared for the reality of holding down a job. We're so bound up with how we can say things, that we're going to need law degrees just to say hello to each other. I find myself communicating less and less with people and spending more time with my horses :D They don't argue semantics. I am patient with our user base who are struggling with how to talk. Trying to .../

Comment: .../ moderate through discussion on how to improve things, rather than just suspending long time users who are being chased by flags. As for new people who come to the site and abuse people without any positive contribution, I'm kick to suspend. All the others in between trying to learn or work as programmers who get stuck, well, it's a cross between being a lifeguard and a policewoman.  (not just as a mod, as a person)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Consider the snipes at the policy a form of civil disobedience, kind of like the 60s sit ins. It's people demonstrating, "No, I am not going to follow your destructive policy, and I'm not leaving either. But I'm going to disobey without hurting anyone."

Comment: @jpmc26 true. I honestly don't know what the solution is. I'm not sure anyone does. What a mess..  *sigh*

Comment: I once thought it was "don't hit me". Seriously.

Comment: Imo, one of the greatest features of the whole SE network is the democratic nature of the voting system. If it's clear that a majority is in favor of something, it makes it much easier to put aside my own opinion and go with it. Conversely, if there is overwhelming opposition expressed by our users to something that's been implemented without being put to any kind of vote, you are going to get some backlash. This is now off topic, but I'm wondering why we don't have a voting system in place to approve or discard decisions about what gets implemented in the mechanics of the site.

Comment: @billynoah Because that system would not matter. This site has owners who decide what gets implemented. (It's not us.)

Comment: If the system was in place then it would matter.  If the site owners ignored it then it wouldn't be a system that was in place.

Comment: @billynoah FWIW site founder [pointed here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) that voting system has limitations and should be complemented by a moderation: "in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..."

Comment: @gnat - nothing wrong with moderation in moderation. In this case though, the established users are literally bending over backwards to express their dislike of this new feature. I just came from reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator where there are literally thousands of upvotes on answers comlaining about the new indicator. And even here we can see the top voted answer shares an (off topic) "personal opinion" of disdain. This hardly falls into the category of *upvoting the easy stuff* or *losing focus on substantive content*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This seems to be pretty universally accepted among mainstream icon designers to represent a waving hand. [See the emojipedia entry for  U+1F44B "Waving Hand Sign"](https://emojipedia.org/waving-hand-sign/).

This image is essentially an all-black version of any of the renderings for U+1F44B:

[image: screen capture from emojipedia showing platform renderings of U+1F44B "Waving Hand Sign"]

---

---

#### **Addendum:**

Facebook uses this icon to mark newcomers to a group. So Stack Overflow is not the only site using this icon in this way.

Comment: Lol - *"This emoji can be used to convey a sense of not being friends any more"*.

Comment: Clearly it's telling long time contributors that Stack Overflow is not friends with them anymore, 'cause the new people are replacing them. 

Comment: Jokes aside, I'm pretty sure we have a significant Chinese user base and I can't help but wonder if this is being received in that context by some of them. 

Comment: On my browser, with my fonts, I need to zoom way in before that emoji looks like anything other than a hand holding an old-school telephone.

Comment: The HTC one appears to be just a hand, I see no movement lines

Comment: Yeah, it may be the universal symbol for waving a hand, but the trouble is that waving a hand has no universal meaning. This seems to be another assumed-global Westernism with no thought gone into the wider user base. :(

Comment: I'm quite confused about the meaning of gesture "waving hand".  In Russia "waving hand" usually means "goodbye".

Answer (score 101):

I interpret it as a waving hand. If you check the HTML, you can figure out that the `<svg>` element has `iconWave` as class name. That confirms my interpretation.

**Personal opinion**:

I have seen the meta post and, to be honest, it is just so silly. It (that indicator) just does not add value IMHO. The code of conduct should apply to everyone, even if they are new to the site. If you are curious if a user is new (having a reputation below 100 is a nice indication), just check their profile, geez. Better yet: why should I treat new users differently? I have said it before and am willing to repeat it again:

> *the code of conduct should apply to **everyone***.

I am experiencing that indicator as noise. Experiencing lots of noise can make a person grumpy.

Comment: Nitpick: experienced users who are suspended also have 1 rep. IMO a better indicator is: a low rep level combined with only a few bronze badges.

Comment: @S.L.Barth suspended users have few chance to ask a question so... I fail to see how this would be applicable.

Comment: @Tensibai It would apply to the posts they already had posted before they got suspended. But, I admit it's nit-picking on my part.

Comment: I think the indicator has to do with their contributions to a particular site. For example I saw a meta post today with the 'New contributor' flag and the user has 1500+ rep on SO and has had their account for over 5 years. That was their first meta post, though.

Comment: I can totally accept if people are rude to me because I was stupid or lazy. It's less nice if I just was lost as a noob. I assume it's similar with most people. So no, the code of conduct (which is just so much fluff anyway, insofar as it extends self-understood nonpathological behavior) does not apply to all people equally. Noobs deserve more leniency. P.S. Experiencing lots of code of conduct can make a person feel they are in a padded cell.

Comment: Why you should treat new users differently? Because they are not as experienced in the rules and cultural expectations in the new community. This is not unique to SO, it applies to most groups in life.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - what if you are lost as a noob _because_ you are stupid or lazy? ;D

Comment: SE has a lot of rules and they're not necessarily clear from a brief statement. An experienced user can be expected to understand what kinds of improvement someone thought their post needed when receiving close votes, and experienced users probably (hopefully) feel welcome as contributors by default. New users might need a bit of help understanding the nuances of the rules, and being more explicit that we welcome them learning the rules and becoming a better contributor encourages them to actually do that. It's not about not holding newbies to the CoC, it's about *helping* them abide by it.

Comment: @Alex No, we shouldn't treat them differently because if we do, they won't break their bad habits. A founding core principle of SO was that it's the *content* that matters, not the person who posted it. A bad post from a 20k user should be treated the same as a bad post by a 1 rep user: pointing out problems, downvotes, flags, closure, and deletion. The same is true for a good post: upvotes and interesting addendums. And we **certainly** shouldn't treat experienced users *worse* than new ones.

Comment: @jpmc26 You can enforce the same rules but still adjust your communication appropriately to fit the different levels of experience of this kind of community. We don't have to be autistic just because we are programmers.

Comment: @Alex No, you should be just as clear and professional whether you're talking to a 20k user or a one day old user. There is nothing special about a new user that requires any different treatment, tone, or actions. Your comment reads as suggesting that we be nicer to new users than to experienced ones, since that is really the only way to vary your communication if you're excluding the content of your responses. If so, that's ridiculous.

Comment: @jpmc26 There is. The special thing about new users is that they are not accustomed to the culture and the practical application of the rules, thus motivates a more forgiving and helpful attitude in order to get them on track while not scaring them away. We can put different expectations on established users.

Comment: @Alex How would you communicate our customs and cultures in a way differently from how you would communicate them to a 20k user who is not following them? You wouldn't. A person is either following them or not following them. Their newness does not matter. Unless you're saying we should be less helpful and forgiving to experienced users, which is ridiculous. Stop thinking of people in terms of classes. Look at them individually and do the best you can in each situation.

Comment: @jpmc26 Of course we can put different expectations on experienced users and hold them to a higher standard. This is like fundamental group dynamics, have you ever joined any community in real life as a beginner and been expected to instantly understand and adhere to all explicit and implicit rules of that community on the same level as a senior? We need new users, so it's rational to be _extra_ helpful and supportive when they begin here. It's not rational to invest in the same support to established users that can be expected to know how SE/SO works.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Stop thinking of people in terms of classes. Look at them individually and do the best you can in each situation." - Appropriate generalisations and abstractions is how we understand and deal with everything in life. You can not work with a system of people effectively without using appropriate generalizations.

Comment: @Alex "Of course we can put different expectations on experienced users and hold them to a higher standard." And this is where you're completely wrong. New users should *not* be held to a lower standard. Doing so is bad for the community and for the site. SO was founded to be a library of useful programming information. Letting new users post low quality content is actively harmful to that goal. A question and answer are either good or bad. The newness of the user makes no difference.

Comment: @Alex "We need new users..." Not really. SO has 10s of thousands of users posting content. We're not short on people, questions, or answers. And we certainly don't need users who aren't willing to actively work hard to meet our standards or whose skin isn't thick enough to stand being downvoted and have their posts critiqued harshly. What we *are* short on is quality content; this actually implies our standards (as applied in practice) are *too low* already.

Comment: @jpmc26 Where have I stated that new users should be allowed to post low quality content? I clearly remember that I explicitly wrote that the same rules should apply to all users. That is not in any way diametrical to being more supportive in the communication with new users, please don't use straw man arguments. And regarding the need of new users, core personnel [don't agree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314302/are-we-creating-divisions-in-our-quest-to-make-new-users-welcome/314519#314519).

Answer (score 31):

Personally, I saw this as a two-handed hand:

- The welcoming hand of the Welcome Wagon
- A polite waving for attention to the message about the "Be Nice" reinforcement.

From what I see from the latest changes, the SE network is attempting to:

- Be more welcoming to new users
- Make a stab of making the website look a bit more modern

I expect to see more of the same kind of thing popping up, at which point I shall:

- Accept that things change
- Assume good intent
- Move on with my life

Edit: Yay, I am wearing the Black Hand of Welcoming!

Comment: Thank you for offering a sensible answer and of note is the welcome and waving hand accompanying your avatar [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ppO.png).

Comment: W̼̝͇͞e͈̣͙̹ ̸̱̥̬͎̘͎̻k̵̻̱̜̳n̻̲͚̰͎̹̳o̲̞̜̬̟̞͞ẉ̨̩.

Comment: *"Be more welcoming to new users"* this is my problem with this answer. While the SE network may be attempting that, frankly, I don't think it's appropriate. It should either be *"Be more welcoming to **all** users"* or not even be mentioned. (This isn't a jab at you personally rather the common consensus that we should be nicer to new users)

Comment: Profile: "Member for 1 year, 11 months". Uhm. ok.

Comment: @totymedli Now that just sounds more sarcastic. FYI Indicator shows for 1 week after 1st post.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl He asked a question on the main site in 2016, he has 50k at The Workplace where he is a moderator, 12k at Worldbuilding and the member of 27 communities...

Comment: And of course, no matter how involved I am in other communities, I am as nothing on StackOverflow.  I know this, it's the way of the world and I accept that.  However, it does raise the point where this "new contributor noob" message appears, despite being an established user on other sites in the network.

Comment: @totymedli According to [the MSE post announcing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator), '*the association bonus won't influence the behavior. While you might not be new to our engine, everyone is new when they first join a new community, so the indicator is shown.*'

Comment: @Snow You have 22 rep on SO (plus assoc. bonus), it is just that you have nothing on MSO.

Answer (score 21):

**ICONS:** ***I***ncomprehensible **C**onfusing **O**bfuscated **N**onsense **S**ymbols

Comment: Did you get that from this book https://www.amazon.com/Buseyisms-Buseys-Instructions-Before-Leaving-ebook/dp/B079Y7LMT6?

Comment: no I made it up myself 20+ years ago

Answer (score 16):

The hand reminds me predominantly of the ISO 3864-2 product safety label "Authorized personnel only" commonly used in mechanical engineering.

Comment: In the meantime, I noticed the identical comment by @TobySpeight on [this similar  answer to the main thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314475/400218).

Comment: And just now the comment by @Lundin on the present question as well.

Answer (score 13):

To me it just looks like a "hey, pay attention" icon. The combination of the icon and text draws more attention than only the text would.

Comment: It would have been an exclamation mark then, not a hand.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, but those are warning signs. ⚠ SE doesn't want these hands to be warning signs. "Be nice, or else..." That is not the message.

Answer (score 7):

I always get alerted when I see that icon 'cause it reminds me of some signs you can find in my country like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It makes me feel under some kind of risk, and it always makes me read the words to be sure of not doing anything wrong or risking something like a suspension of my account.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question, what the icon is supposed to mean. I think this answer would be more suitable [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/168333) on MSE, where they ask for feedback on the new feature.

Answer (score -4):

In sign language, waving both hands in the air means [applauding](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/a/applause.htm). That could totally be what's intended here, since the medium does not transmit sound.

It's also a widely shared (at least where I'm from) way to applaud without disturbing speech in meetings between hundreds of people.

Comment: You _really_ think that's what the icon is supposed to mean? I'm familiar with sign language, but that's about the least likely explanation I'd have come up with.

Comment: @jhpratt I don't know, and I don't really care. People were getting all worked up over OP's round of applause idea, whereas it's really not that far fetched of an idea. It's possibly really not that it is supposed to *mean*, but the hypothesis is acceptable.

Comment: Or, more clearly, I don't have great confidence that it is what's intended, but the likeliness is high enough that round of applause really can't be evaluated as snark or bad faith.

Comment: If that were the intention, they would have gone for [](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%F0%9F%91%8F/)