# Has the homepage always looked like this for non logged in users?

Tags: discussion, homepage

Has the homepage always looked like this:

[image]

Has the point of SO always been about developers this, developers that, productivity growth discovery blah blah, or might it have been about Q&A? Maybe make the homepage just a LITTLE more about Q&A and **asking questions**?

Or is [all of this changing?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) Is [the Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387651/the-world-is-big-and-i-am-so-small-what-are-the-implications-for-our-meta-commu?cb=1) [having less of a say?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator?cb=1)