# Saved Questions And Answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, bookmarks

I think a good feature would be a save/bookmark feature which lets you bookmark a question or save it to a specific list and have an option to create custom lists (same as YouTube and other social media sites have)

So, for example, let's say I see a question that I want to read but not now, I should be able to add it to my "Save for later" list Or lets say I see a JS  question about arrays and I think I might need it one day I should be able to add it to my "Array Helpers" or my "JS Array Questions"

Comment: Like *mark as favorite question*?

Comment: No, like add it to a specific list

Comment: I can't find something in a pool of "Favorite Questions"

Comment: Welcome to Meta, by the way @Moishe :).  Votes here are different than at the main site:  people will vote up if it's useful, well researched, *and* they agree with it, or downvote if you didn't do your research or they don't like the idea.

Comment: All the best on this one though, I think it would be a cool feature.  I think a lot of people here have other feature requests they'd rather have implemented, but I think this is a good idea fwiw.

Comment: You can save a browser shorcut that *searches* inside your favorited questions using `infavorites:yourIDNo "searchterm"`

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't understand,   Can you show me an example?

Comment: Go to your profile and look at the "Favorites" tab. In the search bar type `infavorites:5144943 "arrays"` and any question that you have starred that contains the word "arrays" will show up.

Comment: You can save **that** result as a browser shortcut.

Comment: Duplicate MSE (answer) feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319449/253521 Specifically the "Favorites Tab" section part-way down.

Comment: @Paulie_D that's not necessarily going to do what OP wants. Here is an example of what I'd use this for: I add a question as a favoirite for one of few reasons 1) old question, has answers - I want to read it later 2) new question, some or no answers  - I want to see how it develops 3) old question, has useful information - I want to be able to get to it quickly. So, basically three lists Stuff to Read, Stuff to Follow, Fast Access. There is no real search that can distinguish between these.

Answer (score 5):

The functionality you requested is not available (yet) from Stack Exchange.

What you can do is save a **browser shorcut** that searches inside your favorited questions using `infavorites:yourIDNo "yousearchterm"`

For instance, my favorited questions on [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox)

[image]

Comment: Clever workaround! But is the OP not asking for this functionality to be made available? Is stuff like that not meant for Meta? (i.e. Only requests for what can be done by mods?)

Comment: @jake [meta is not meant for that anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387651/424903), no.

Comment: @Gimby Ah, I see. Give the community just enough sense of importance so SE doesn't have to pay for administration, free answers to questions, traffic, etc. Manipulation. If only this was a non-profit!

Answer (score 4):

With the launch of the [Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) recently, this is now possible. Custom lists can be created to organize your favorite saved content (now supporting saving answers as well!) As such, I've added the [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) label.