# Is it possible to save questions and answers to latest selected list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, saves

Perhaps you can see this as a further step of this question: [Saved Questions And Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387874/saved-questions-and-answers)

Currently, Stack Overflow allows people to save questions and answers to different lists by clicking on the "Manage" button (huge thanks to @devs for implementing it):

[image: save-button-clicked-indication-banner]

However, no matter what lists I have saved previously, for example, I searched through the tag of `ReactJS`, and saved an answer to the `ReactJS-example` list; then I navigated to another answer to the same question, and the answer I saved would default to the `For later` list again.

It would be great if the behaviour is to default save to the latest list I saved, then change it through "Manage" button.

Or to allow changing the default list to save through Settings.

Comment: Re *"default save to the latest list I saved"*: Or a settable default list. It is the most obvious evolution of this feature. Until then, a workaround is [some automation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394457/make-clicking-manage-after-saving-a-post-auto-focus-the-list-selection-dropdow#comment1318941_394457). I have used a [macro key](https://keyboardsexpert.com/macropad-mechanical-keyboard-faqs/) for some time now to move the current save to a preferred list; it works well (and is much faster than manual).